# Обновить запись по атрибуту Yii2 Active Record

Tags: php, yii2

Есть модель

```
<?php

class UserDiscuss extends ActiveRecord
{

const SCENARIO_COMMENT = 'comment';
const SCENARIO_ANSWER = 'answer';


public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_COMMENT] = ['fromUser', 'toUser', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'comment'];
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_ANSWER] = ['answer', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    return $scenarios;
}

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'user_discuss';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['fromUser', 'toUser', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['comment', 'answer'], 'string'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'fromUser' => 'From User',
        'toUser' => 'To User',
        'comment' => 'Comment',
        'answer' => 'Answer',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
    ];
}

}
```

и Action в контроллере

```
     public function actionIndex()
{
        $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
        $user = User::findPrivatePerson($id);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('error', 'user_not_found'));
        }

        $modelDiscuss = null;
        if (Yii::$app->user->id == $user->id) {
            $modelDiscuss = new UserDiscuss(['scenario' => UserDiscuss::SCENARIO_ANSWER]);
        } else {
            $modelDiscuss = new UserDiscuss(['scenario' => UserDiscuss::SCENARIO_COMMENT]);
        }


        if ($modelDiscuss->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelDiscuss->save()) {
            return $this->redirect('/user/'.$id);
        } else {
            return $this->render('index', [
                'user' => $user,
                'cityArray' => User2City::getCityArrayByUserId($user->id),
                'modelDiscuss' => $modelDiscuss
            ]);
        }
}
```

При сценарии SCENARIO_COMMENT все отрабатывает нормально.
[image: phpmyadmin]

Теперь как мне сделать, чтобы при сценарии SCENARIO_ANSWER, при вызове метода save в контроллере, оно находило запись по toUser, и обновляло добавляя в запись answer. Просто не хочется пилить кастомный метод, который будет искать и обновлять запись. Хотелось бы услышать ответ как сделать это средствами yii2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате переписал контроллер

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        $userId = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
        $user = User::findPrivatePerson($userId);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('error', 'user_not_found'));
        }
        $modelDiscuss = null;
        $userDiscussArray = UserDiscuss::findAll(['toUser' => $userId]);

        if (Yii::$app->user->id == $user->id) {
            $modelDiscuss = new UserDiscuss(['scenario' => UserDiscuss::SCENARIO_ANSWER]);
        } else {
            $modelDiscuss = new UserDiscuss(['scenario' => UserDiscuss::SCENARIO_COMMENT]);
        }

        if ($modelDiscuss->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            if ($modelDiscuss->scenario == $modelDiscuss::SCENARIO_ANSWER) {
                $id = Yii::$app->request->post(UserDiscuss::CLASS_NAME)['id'];
                $answer = Yii::$app->request->post(UserDiscuss::CLASS_NAME)['answer'];
                UserDiscuss::updateAll(['updated_at' => time(), 'answer' => $answer], ['id' => $id]);
            } else {
                $modelDiscuss->save();
            }

            return $this->redirect('/user/'.$userId);

        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Kyryll Maesh is very cool men!");
            return $this->render('index', [
                'user' => $user,
                'cityArray' => User2City::getCityArrayByUserId($user->id),
                'modelDiscuss' => $modelDiscuss,
                'userDiscussArray' => $userDiscussArray,
                'commentCount' => count($userDiscussArray)
            ]);
        }
}
```

Дописал проверку по сценариям + добавил в контроллере updateAll